# set attribute of xml node to a variable

Tags: jquery, xml, variables

I am trying to get the value of an attribute of an XML node and set it as a variable using JQuery.  Is this possible?

```
<DataContainer>
    <Customers>
        <Customer customerId="7366" customerName="Boardwalk Audi" url="" 
            address="5930 West Plano Pkwy" city="Plano" state="Texas" 
            zipCode="75093" latitude="33.0160690000000000" 
            longitude="-96.8268970000000000">
    <Customers>
<DataContainer>
```

I want to set the customerId attribute of 7366 as a variable for later use like below:

```
$customerId = customer id from xml node attribute;
```

Is this possible?  Let me know if you need any more clarification.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing this, Canavar.  I always forget about the 4 space indent to make the readable code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fetching the XML in an ajax request you can just use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the node and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the attriute, for example:

```
var cust_id = $(xml).find("Customer").attr("customerId");
```

[You can see an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/AptrJ/), keep in mind this is intended to be used in an ajax callback ultimately using `responseXML` (not just an XML string), but you get the idea :)

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm!  I should've known to just use a selector.  Thanks for the super quick help.  And i love the link...i'll be using that a lot i'm sure!

Comment: Is there a way to combine variables if i am doing something similar to your code above.  If i get the address, city, state, and zipCode values can i combine them into one variable that would output as "5930 West Plano Pkwy, Plano, Texas, 75093"?  Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanPitts - Yeah you can get them all as variables or use a single string, e.g. `var n =  $(xml).find("Customer"); var output = n.attr("address") + ", " + n.attr("city") + ", " + n.attr("state") + ", " + n.attr("zipCode");` or take an array and `.join(", ")`...whatever method really, all the same approach.