# Set new Attribute in XML using jQuery

Tags: php, xml

i want to add new attribute in XML using jquery

for e.g:
XML:

new XML i want display as:

```
<data>
<section marked="marked"></section>
</data>
```

from above i want to add `marked="marked"` attribute using jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set attribute of xml node to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713080/set-attribute-of-xml-node-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add attribute in any XML tag as you add in HTML

First your XML is saved in any variable

```
var a = '<data><section></section></data>';
```

**Edit**

Now you have to add this line too and it will work fine.

```
a = $(a);
```

This line will add an attribute in `section` tag

```
a.find('section').attr('marked', 'marked');
```

Comment: hi
i've tried above code but its giving '[object Object]' output.

Comment: @Jay Please check my updated answer.

Sorry for missing the edited line.

Comment: i trying with '   var a = '<data><section></section></data>';
   a = $(a);
   a.find('section').attr('marked', 'marked');
   alert(a);'

but same output :(

Comment: @Jay Yeah because after doing `a = $(a)` the variable `a` is now jQuery Object. To get modified xml you have to do this `a[0].outerHTML`.